# What's the difference between "europe" and "european-union" tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

[europe](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe):

> For questions that relate to the laws, practices, and products of the European Union.

[european-union](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/european-union):

> for questions that relate to the laws, practices, and products of the European Union (EU).

I don't see any difference.

- Point in favor of merger: the descriptions are the same.
- Point against merger: there are places in Europe that are not in the European Union (e.g. Russia, UK, etc.).

Comment: I think there's some mostly irrelevant island a bit north of France too.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica Apologies, I've now added those irrelevant islands.

Comment: It's ok, it was just a joke at our expense :-) It was sufficiently covered by the "etc" anyway. There's also more complicated cases like Switzerland, Norway etc.

Answer (score 2):

To make them different, [europe](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe) could be changed to "*… of European countries outside the European Union*".

But what would be the point?
It's not like there are groups of countries with similar laws, shared currencies, etc. other than the EU itself.
So any questions using this tag would almost always be about a single country (or implicitly about the EU by asking how other countries differ from it).

Unless a good purpose can be found for the [europe](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe) tag, it should be an alias.

But really, since there aren't tags for any other continent (why would there be?), **just get rid of it**, and retag the existing questions.

(*Yes, there is* [australia](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australia)*, but that's for the country; that it's also the name of the continent is irrelevant.*)

Comment: There's [tag:south-east-asia].